# Converting string value to integer

Tags: vb.net, converters

How to convert string select max to integer, thanks

```
Sub locking()
    Dim nomortrans As Integer
    Dim SQL As StrinG
    SQL = "select MAX(s_nomor_trans) from tblpos_trans_nomor"
    Proses.ExecuteNonQuery(SQL)
    frm_pos.LblNomorTransaksi.Text = SQL 
    frm_pos3.LblNomorTransaksi.Text = SQL 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question: What are you expecting? What is the actual outcome?

Comment: I want to select max value into textboxt.text, sorry my english is bad.. thanks sir

Comment: Which language are you using? Is this basic?

Comment: Yes its vb.net...